# Prevent Foundation modal from closing on form submit

Tags: jquery, flask, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

How do I prevent the modal from closing once the form has been submitted? I am using Flask & Jinja.

```
<form method="post" action="" id="login-form">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="{{request.form.username}}"/>
   <input type="Password" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="{{request.form.password}}"/>
   <button id="submit-button" class="success button" data-toggle="modal">Login/Register</button>
   <p>{{error}}</p>
   <script>
   $('#submit-button').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login-form').submit();
     });
   </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form, by default, loads the page identified in the action attribute.
A blank action `action=""` will reload the current page by default.

To keep the modal open you will have to check for the form submission (upon the load of the page) and make the modal active if you found that the form data had been submitted.

The other method to do this would be to submit the form data using ajax.